# openlayers cluster strategy - exhibiting custom icons for clusters of 1 feature

Tags: openlayers-2, clustering

i have a page that displays a **vector layer** imported from a **kml file** (basically like the the [sundials example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials.html)).  it works perfectly well, both using fixed strategy ONLY, as well as using both fixed and CLUSTER strategies simultaneously.

i would like to create a **hybrid display**, whereas **"clusters of 1 feature"** would be displayed with the original **custom icon** contained in the KML file under `<Style><IconStyle><Icon><href>img/arrowRed.png`, for example.

right now, **if i use cluster strategy, clusters of 1 (feature) are displayed using the default icon** (yellow disk).

i would rather not use any plugins or libraries that aren't standard openlayers.   **any suggestions?**

below a part of the original javascript code using clusters (remove the cluster strategy declaration `new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()` and custom icons are displayed just fine):

```
var urlKMLClient = 'KMLClientsAll.kml'; 
var layerKMLClient = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Clients", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster(), refresh],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: urlKMLClient,
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true, 
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
            })
        })
    });
```

[image: WITHOUT CLUSTER]

see Client custom icon (green marker) gives way to cluster default icon (yellow disk) below

[image: WITH CLUSTER]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({threshold:2})` this allows thad isolated points they are not in a cluster.

Comment: spot on.  UPVOTED!   thank you very much for taking the time to answer the question.  this seems to be confirmation of what i had found to be a solution a couple of days ago.  IF you are  a stackOverflow member, please answer my question there and i will award you the solution also (i feel that awarding myself the correct answer is weird somehow): http://stackoverflow.com/q/15300467/1166727